# Python, массив объектов

Tags: python

Допустим есть массив объектов:

```
array = [{'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}]
```

Перебираю, но как проверить есть ли у объекта свойство unique

Comment: Проверить наличие ключа в словаре можно двумя способами: 1. 'key' in dict. 2. dict.get('key') == None

Comment: @Sergey K. если в `unique` будет `None`, то второй вариант даст сбой

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Danis, это как альтернатива, если может не важно существует ключ или нет, а важно наличие значения)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array = [{'x': 'x', 'y': 'y', 'unique': True}, 
         {'x': 'x', 'y': 'y'}, 
         {'x': 'x', 'y': 'y', 'unique': True}]

for dict in array:
  if 'unique' in dict:
    print(True)
  else:
    print(False)

#True
#False
#True
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1602934).

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать ваш `array` буквально, как вы выразились, "массив объектов", то это список объектов класса `dict` и его ключи не являются атрибутами:

```
d = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}
getattr(d, 'unique')
'''
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

Если вы хотите чтобы ключи были именно атрибутами, то можно сделать из словарей объекты класса. Тогда у них будут соответствующие свойства и, как вы и хотите, можно будет проверить наличие нужного свойства. Например, примерно так:

```
array = [{'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}]

class Unique:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

array = [Unique(d) for d in array]

for u in array:
    print(hasattr(u, 'unique'))
'''
True
False
True
```

Но если вы хотите, чтобы объекты массива остались словарями и при этом у них еще были и свойства, то это тоже можно. Создаем класс, наследуясь от класса `dict`. Примерно так:

```
array = [{'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y}, 
         {'x': x, 'y': y, 'unique': True}]

class UniqueDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d):
        super().__init__(d)
        self.__dict__ = self
        
d_array = [UniqueDict(d) for d in array]

d_array[0]
'''
{'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y', 'unique': True}
'''
d_array[0].unique
'''
True
```

Если же вам просто нужна проверка наличия в словаре определенного ключа, то тут уже рассказали как это сделать.